# What programming language and framework is used to write the Google site (more interested in the frontend)?

Tags: frameworks, frontend, gmail

What programming language and framework is used to write the Google site (Google.com, Gmail, Google Docs, and developers.Google)(more interested in the frontend)?

Answer (score 1):

Google is using following technologies:

**Frontend:** Javascript And Typescript
**Backend:** C, C++, PHP, Go, Java, Python, TI-BASIC and Node
**Databases:** MariaDb and Bigtable